# how can i force screen to detach *instead of* exit/logout?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I use screen all the time and am constantly attaching/detaching from different sessions. Occasionally I'll accidentally logout/exit instead of detach, losing the buffer of my work on that project. I'd rather not have the detach (ctl-a ctl-d) and exit (ctl-d) commands be so close.

Is there a way to force screen to only ever detach instead of exit?

Comment: You could remap screen's keyboard shortcuts to make accidents less likely, but there's nothing screen can do after you press Ctrl-D - the shell is already dead.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: But since the shell runs inside of `screen`, shouldn't `screen` see Ctrl+D first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem isn't `screen`, it's the shell inside of it. You can make it ignore <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or handle it differently. For BASH, try

```
export IGNOREEOF=4
```

which means you'll have to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> 4 times to exit the shell.

See this question for more solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/how-can-i-keep-controld-from-disconnecting-my-session

Comment: thanks aaron, did a search here and on goog but didnt see that question.